# Assert.IsInstanceOfType fails even though it says both types are the same

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

How can this happen? And How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Do you get any build warnings about a type being defined in more than one assembly...?

Comment: This is probably an MVC version issue due to a missing <bindingRedirect>.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My *guess* (and I stress it is just a guess) is that the test assembly and the assembly under test either reference different versions of the `System.Web.Mvc` assembly, or one is ultimately resolving a different version.  Either way, ultimately the test assembly is expecting one version, and the assembly under test is returning another.

Try doing a clean then a full rebuild, and check other culprits like the web.config binding redirects as @SLaks points out in the comments.

Comment: oh yeah, that was it. I had a reference to System.Web.Mvc of version 4.0.0 in the test project and 3.0.0 in the WebUI project. I just made them both be 3.0.0 and that solved it.